A weird integral
It needs to be noted that he whole motivation is to find an expression for $u(\tau)$ in the end, where u is the scale factor ($u = \frac{a}{a_0}$) and $\tau = H_0 t$.
I'm having issues with solving the integral
$$\tau(u) = \int_0^u \frac{du'}{\sqrt{\varepsilon^{-1} - \Omega_{PH}u'^{-3(w+1)}}}$$
Where $\varepsilon$ and $\Omega_{PH}$ are constants.
Using Wolfram Alpha, I found
$$\int_{1}^{x}\frac{dx'}{\sqrt{b - cx'^y}} = \frac{x'\sqrt{1-\frac{cx'^y}{b}} _1F_2\left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{y}; 1 + \frac{1}{y}; \frac{cx'^y}{b}\right)}{\sqrt{b - cx'^y}},$$
with $_1F_2\left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{y}; 1 + \frac{1}{y}; \frac{cx'^y}{b}\right)$ being the hypergeometric function. I did not get a result that allowed me to retrieve $u(\tau)$ without gross simplifications. Is there anyone who might have an idea on how to solve this in a better way?
If you have any questions about how I got here, ask :)

"If you have any questions about how I got here, ask" - You should provide all context you think is relevant in the question instead, it is your job to ask, and ours to answer.

"Weird has a weird spelling"

You shouldn't expect to find closed forms for $u(\tau)$ for all but a handful of exponents $y$ (probably some subset of $\left{-2, -1, -\frac12, 0, \frac12, 1, 2\right}$. Would you be content with series approximations as, e.g., $x \to 0$ or $x \to \left(\frac{b}c\right)^{\frac1y}$?
